# Vector subscript out of range and polymorphism

Tags: c++

in one of my exercise, I have to write the cpp of the header file : triangle and polygon

In the triangle.h file I have:

```
class Triangle : public Polygon
{
 public:
  Triangle(Point, Point, Point);
  ~Triangle();
 private:
};
```

So in the cpp file of triangle I do this :

```
Triangle::Triangle(Point a, Point b, Point c)
{
 _points[0] = a;
 _points[1] = b;
 _points[2] = c;
}
Triangle::~Triangle(){}
```

Moreover in the polygon file the header file that I have is like below :

```
class Polygon
 { 
  public:
   Polygon();
   ~Polygon();
   virtual double perimeter() const;
  protected:
   vector<Point> _points;
```

};

So I complete the cpp of this file like this :

```
 Polygon::Polygon(){}
 Polygon::~Polygon(){}
 double Polygon::perimeter() const
 {
  return 0.0;
 }
```

But when I want to compile the compiler display the error: vector subscripting out of range and I don't understand when I put things in the vector out of the range. So If you have an idea how to solve the problem, help me.
Thanks you !

Comment: Instead of `_points[0] = a;`, `_points[1] = b;`, `_points[2] = c;` use `push_back` `_points.push_back(a); _points.push_back(b); _points.push_back(c);` or initialize it properly inside the constructor `this->_points = vector<Point>(3);`

Comment: Is it compiler giving error or you are running the program and an exception is thrown? `vector<Point> _points;` is set to size 0 by default. Now, when you access `_points[0]` or anything beyond, you are going out of range. Use `push_back()` instead. As a beginner, you can also use `vector::at()` method instead of `[]` for better exception visibility. On side note, pass `Point a, b, c` by const references to avoid extra copying in constructor.

Comment: inheritance without virtual dtors... What C++ training class is that? o.O

Answer (score 2):

Because your vector is not initialized with a proper size:

```
Triangle::Triangle(Point a, Point b, Point c)
{
 _points.resize(3); // reserve space for 3 points.
 _points[0] = a;
 _points[1] = b;
 _points[2] = c;
}
```

Or use push_back:

```
Triangle::Triangle(Point a, Point b, Point c)
{
 _points.push_back(a);
 _points.push_back(b);
 _points.push_back(c);
}
```